# protobuf-net causing Invalid wire type error during deserialization

Tags: deserialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, protobuf-java, protobuf-net.grpc

Working on a POC of transitioning from BinaryFormater to Protobuf for Serialization and deserialization inorder to reduce the deserialization time. While trying to deserialize using the protobuf library I get the following error "Invalid wire-type; this usually means you have over-written a file without truncating or setting the length" while deserializing a file in a rest web API project but the same code runs fine in another web job project with same .Net version.

protobuf-net Version: 3.1.26

.NET version: .NET framework 4.6.2

Seems to be maybe an internal package dependency version issue or issue if the deserialization happens in a w3 process.

Has anyone faced such issues with the protobuf-net package for a REST service.

Below is the code where the ProtoDeserialize function throws a exception  Serializer.Deserialize<T>(stream) is called

```
[ProtoContract]
    public class Temp
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string name;

        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public int no;
    }
    
[HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage DerserializeProtoBuf()
        {

    try
                    {
                       
                        var x1 = new Temp();
                        x1.name = "testData";
                        x1.no = 10;

                        var data1 = ProtoSerialize<Temp>(x1);

                        var y = ProtoDeserialize<Temp>(data1); // throws exception
                    }

                    catch
                    {
                       
                    }
}

public static T ProtoDeserialize<T>(byte[] data) where T : class
        {
            if (null == data) return null;

            try
            {
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data))
                {
                    using (var decompressor = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                    {
                        return Serializer.Deserialize<T>(stream); // throws Invalid wire-type error here
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidDataException(String.Format("Invalid data format when proto deserializing {0}", typeof(T).Name), ex);
            }
        }

        public static byte[] ProtoSerialize<T>(T record) where T : class
        {
            if (null == record) return null;

            try
            {
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                    {
                        Serializer.Serialize(gZipStream, record);
                    }
                    return stream.ToArray();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidDataException(String.Format("Invalid data format when proto serializing {0}", typeof(T).Name), ex);
            }
        }
```

1. I have tried adding the package dependencies versions explicilty by adding bindingRedirects.
2. Have tried updating and degrading the version of protobuf to 2.3.7 and other before versions

Comment: Side note: unless your data is dominated by text, or is pretty large: I suspect gzip isn't going to help hugely. Obviously measure, though.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `decompressor` instead of `stream` to `Deserialize`. You're passing it the compressed gzip data instead of the decompressed protobuf payload.